# Ruby regex for checking if 2 words exist with correct capital of first letter of each

Tags: ruby, regex

I have achieved checking if capitalization exists with the first letter of each word with the below,

```
NAME_CAPS = /^\p{Lu}\S*{2,}(?:[[:space:]]+\p{Lu}\S*{2,})*$/
```

Maintaining that, I would like to also add to check if 2 words are inserted, you can see my attempt above by adding the `{2,}`. Currently the problem is, it will pass as correct with only one word inserted by the user with correct capitalization - 2 words must be inserted.

More relevant code:

```
def valid_name?(name)
    !!name.match(NAME_CAPS)
end

puts "Now, go for it!"

while (name=gets)

    names = name.split(" ", 2)
    if valid_name?(name)
        puts "Correct."
        break
        else

        puts "Wrong."
    end
end
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How could I extend my working regex, to also incorporate validating 2 words exist

Comment: This any good? `name.match?(/\A[A-Z]\w+\s[A-Z]\w+\z/)`

Comment: Probably something like [`^(?:\b\s*\p{Lu}\S*){2}$`](http://rubular.com/r/WJU9Xz3Mbb) would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change zero-or-more repetition (`*`) to one-or-more repetition (`+`) in the second word group:

```
NAME_CAPS = /^\p{Lu}\S*{2,}(?:[[:space:]]+\p{Lu}\S*{2,})+$/
```

Btw this patter will match longer sequences as well:

```
pry> 'Joe'.match(NAME_CAPS)
=> nil
pry> 'Joe Doe'.match(NAME_CAPS)
=> #<MatchData "Joe Doe">
pry> 'Joe Doe Zoe'.match(NAME_CAPS)
=> #<MatchData "Joe Doe Zoe">
```

To avoid it (and simplify the pattern) you can resign from the repetition:

```
NAME_CAPS = /^\p{Lu}\S*{2,}(?:[[:space:]]+\p{Lu}\S*{2,})$/
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you're trying to do this with a regex, but you can also do this:

```
def valid_name?(name)
  names = name.split
  names.size == 2 && names.all?{|n| n == n.capitalize}
end

valid_name?("john doe") #=> false
valid_name?("John Doe") #=> true
valid_name?("John")     #=> false
valid_name?("John Q Doe") #=> false
```